# 2 Names the Same in WCF Not possible?

Tags: wcf

I'm trying to create a RESTful WCF service.  I get a runtime error saying you can't have 2 of the same method names in your service class:

```
    [OperationContract, WebGet]
    ...
    string Get();

    [OperationContract, WebGet]
    ...
    string Get(int id);
```

Why in the world can't you!  they are both different signatures.   If I'm to get this to work like REST like I want, which is to be able to overload stuff like this, then that would suck and WCF is not for me.

Has anyone been able to have 2 of the same method names in your so-called attempt to make WCF restful?

Comment: You'll have to define separate routes. You'll probably figure out how to do that faster than I will...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can override service method by using **OperationContract** name property with define separate routes.Your service interface should look like

```
    [OperationContract(Name = "GetemployeeName")]
    string Get(string param);


    [OperationContract(Name = "GetemployeeAge")]
    bool Get(long sysID);
```